# have div content update when variable changes in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, updates

i have searched around but cant find exactly what i need. i want the div, which contains a variable value, to update every time the variable changes. is this possible? without reloading the whole page, as this would reset the variable value.

```
<head>
<script> var eg=30</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> 30 </div>

<button onclick=eg++>increase</button>
</body>
```

how would i then make the div containing the number update

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your variable to div after update it.

```
 <head>
 <script> var eg=30</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="mydiv"> 30 </div>
 <button onclick='eg++; document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = eg;'>increase</button>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = your_var;
```

Add this on the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script> var eg=30</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display"> 30 </div>
<button onclick="eg++;document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = eg;">Increase</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a function that both increases the counter, and updates the div. Then, call that function from onclick. If you place your script at the botton, you can easily remove all the inline scripts from your HTML, which would make it more organized and easier to read:

```
<body>
    <div id="egDiv"> 30 </div>
    <button id="egButton">increase</button>

    <script> 
    var eg=30

    // Function to increase the counter
    function increaseEg() {
        eg++;
        document.getElementById('egDiv').innerHTML = eg;
    }

    // Add onclick handler, the simplest way:
    document.getElementById('egButton').onclick = increaseEg;
    </script>
</body>
```